# Plots for more than one series with "sparkTable" package

Tags: r, sparktable

If I understand it correctly, the `sparkTable` package allows for multiple kinds of plots, but only on one series. So, for example, if my dataset `df` looks like this:

> ```
> variable  value   time
> Level_1   34  1947
> Level_1   38  1948
> Level_1   17  1949
> Level_1   61  1950
> Level_1   19  1951
> Level_1   80  1952
> Level_1   57  1953
> Level_1   66  1954
> ```

i.e. the variable "value" changes over "time" across the levels of "variable", then I can draw, for instance, sparklines and bargraphs of "value" for different levels of "variable" with the following code:

```
library(sparkTable)
content<-list()
content[['LinePlot']]<-newSparkLine()
content[['BarPlot']]<-newSparkBar()

varType<-rep("value",2)
df<-df[,c("variable","value","time")]
df$time<-as.numeric(as.character(df$time))
dat<-reshapeExt(df,idvar="variable",varying=list(2))
sparkTab<-newSparkTable(dat,content,varType)
plotSparkTable ( sparkTab , outputType = "html", filename = "t1")
```

But is there any way to graph more than one series in the same output? For example, let's say I want to have one sparkline for "value", and another for cumulative of the "value" series over time (calculated by `Cumulative_Value = ave(df$value, df$variable, FUN=cumsum)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean adding extra rows to the resulting sparkTable?

**EDIT**: OP wants adding extra columns, not rows.

### Adding extra columns

To add extra columns you just have to update `df`, `content` and `varType` to include the cumulative values. Add the following into your code:

```
# with the other lines defining content:
content[['Cumulative']] <- newSparkLine()

# add the following to your df
df$cumulative = ave(df$value, df$variable, FUN=cumsum)

# add the following to your varType definition
varType <- c('value','value','cumulative')
```

The rest can stay the same.

The first line adds another spark line column to your table, the second calculates the `cumulative` column and adds it to your data frame, and the third tells `newSparkTable` that the first two plots are for the `value` column and the last for the `cumulative` column.

[image]

### Adding extra rows

The only way I know (and it's not very nice) is to add extra rows to your `df`, each corresponding to the cumulative value.

For example:

```
# make dummy data table with Levels 1 2 3,
#  years 1947:1966 for each, and
#  values being random from 1 to 100.
years <- 1947:1966
n     <- length(years)
df    <- data.frame( variable=sprintf('Level_%i',rep(1:3,each=n)), value=sample(100,3*n,replace=T), time=years )

# as before (setting up spark table)
library(sparkTable)
content<-list()
content[['LinePlot']]<-newSparkLine()
content[['BarPlot']]<-newSparkBar()

# ** calculate cumulative value, and APPEND to the dataframe
# There is a different cumulative line for *each* level.
# Hence we need to make new factors 
#  Level_1_cumulative, Level_2_cumulative, Level_3_cumulative
cv  <- ave(df$value, df$variable, FUN=cumsum)
df2 <- rbind(df, data.frame( variable=sprintf('Level_%i_cumulative',rep(1:3,each=n)), value=cv, time=years ))

# as before (make sparktable, but use df2 this time)
dat<-reshapeExt(df2,idvar="variable",varying=list(2))
varType<-rep("value",2)
sparkTab<-newSparkTable(dat,content,varType)
plotSparkTable ( sparkTab , outputType = "html", filename = "t1")
```

I end up with something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for jumping in, MathCof. I want to add extra columns, not rows. That is, I want values, bars and cumulative values for every level to be plotted in adjacent boxes, one row for each level.